# Delphi IDE flickers from time to time

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I worked with various Delphi versions: 3...7 and 10.0 and never experienced any flickering issues. Now I am working with XE5 and experience from time to time an IDE panels flickering. During this flickering the user interface of the IDE is completely locked and does not accept key presses or mouse clicks.

It happens irregularly: sometimes once a day, sometimes two or three times in a row.

I supposed that this is the IDE bug, found some "solution" that stated I should delete some components from palette. It didn't help.

A couple of days ago I tried application screen sharing for Microsoft Teams, and the IDE window flickered  like crazy. So my new supposition is: the IDE window flickers when some application tries to capture its window.

Do you have an idea how to find out which application is spying on Delphi IDE and makes screenshots of it from time to time?

I'm in Windows 10.

Comment: The IDE is (very) buggy. The only thing we can do is to point this out to Embarcadero.

Comment: So far 10.4.1 has been a lot better in this regard for me.

Comment: On Win10, I found XE4-XE7 all very unstable and prone to display quirks.  However, Delphi Seattle and later have all been fine on the same system.  Give a recent Delphi version a try ...

Comment: @MartynA: Unfortunately, my experience is not the same. Since the IDE was made themed and got its titlebar controls, I see quirks and bugs everywhere. The positive thing is that it seems like Embarcadero is listening to the feedback they have been receiving lately. 10.4.1, although still buggy, does fix a number of issues.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Interesting, I wonder if the machine spec has anything to do with it (I use an ageing Lenovo T430)?  Anyway, I found the XEx versions borderline unusable whereas Seattle+ mostly behave themselves.

Comment: In case you are using GExperts, compiled a new GExperts DLL yourself from recent sources and have enabled the "Filter Exception" expert this might be related to this. It's a side effect of that expert ignoring an exception. So if there are many exceptions the IDE will flicker like there is no tomorrow.

Comment: It can be linked to System Policy updates as explained here: [link]https://community.embarcadero.com/component/easydiscuss/delphi-project-ui-flicker?Itemid=1
If an application has AppEvents component, it catches this flickers on OnSettingChange event.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem sometimes when I execute in debug mode, because the IDE's windows resize itself automatically to fullscreen when it's already fullscreen and I use 2 or more monitors. I suspect it's a border size problem that can't adjust beetween 2 screens. To avoid this I just manually resize the IDE to not be fullscreen.